# 織田信長 pitch accent

Tags: names, pitch-accent

If I hear correctly, I think 豊臣秀吉 is とよとみひでよし{LHHHLHLL} and 明智光秀 あけちみつひで{LHHLHLL}. What about 織田信長? Is it pronounced multiple ways?

- おだのぶなが{LHLHHH} [1](https://youtu.be/ZUxv47uigyE?t=634), [2](https://youtu.be/gL3p_c3_VWA?t=926), also [the top one here](https://forvo.com/word/%E7%B9%94%E7%94%B0%E4%BF%A1%E9%95%B7/#ja)
- おだのぶなが{LHLHLL} [3](https://youtu.be/BvauQt6xxMc?t=973), [4](https://youtu.be/9EzY_w3kDi8?t=81), also [the second one here](https://forvo.com/word/%E7%B9%94%E7%94%B0%E4%BF%A1%E9%95%B7/#ja)
- [The third one](https://forvo.com/word/%E7%B9%94%E7%94%B0%E4%BF%A1%E9%95%B7/#ja) sounds like おだのぶなが{HLLHLL}

Comment: The first and third on Forvo are not good samples. The first one sounds like おだのぶなが{LHLLLL}. The speaker of the third one has a Kansai accent. He says おだのぶなが{HHLHLL}.

Comment: [天下人アクセント](https://mobile.twitter.com/Loyuka_nua2/status/1533291000377946112)ですね…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I  would say the most accepted accent is おだのぶなが{LHHHLL}. [#3, #4, and the second clip on Forvo]

That’s when his name is said in full. When the surname is omitted, it should be either のぶなが{LHLL} or のぶなが{LHHH}. The flat, or flattened, accent may be more common now.

It seems some people use this flat accent even when they say his name in full, like おだのぶなが{LHHHHH}. [#1 and #2] It sounds a bit awkward to me.

Actually, the same can be said about 豊臣秀吉 and 徳川家康, too.

> とよとみひでよし{LHHHHHLL}
>
> ひでよし{LHLL} or ひでよし{LHHH}

> とくがわいえやす{LHHHHHLL}
>
> いえやす{LHLL} or いえやす{LHHH}

とよとみひでよし{LHHHHHHH} and とくがわいえやす{LHHHHHHH} sound even weirder than おだのぶなが{LHHHHH}. It may be simply because they are longer.

Few parents choose to name their children のぶなが or いえやす, but ひでよし is not an uncommon name compared to the other two. They would be called ひでよし{LHLL}, not ひでよし{LHHH}. It’s like the flattening of the accent gives it a special status.

明智光秀 is a bit different.

> あけちみつひで{LHHHHLL}
>
> みつひで{LHLL}

Few people say みつひで{LHHH}. This may be a sign that he is not considered to be worthy of the special status the other three have earned.

Comment: I think I am still struggling to tell if a mora drops in the middle of a word. I listened to the first forvo clip a couple more times, but I still seem to hear it as having a low の. How can I be certain if a mora inside a word drops or not?

Comment: @EddieKal - If you are talking about the first clip on Forvo, you are correct. It does drop on の. Please read my comment to the question.